# Having some trouble while using regex and pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Iam working in a project to convert some invoices in PDFs to .xlsx for comparision reasons, but i ran into some trouble, in the conversion phase the program separated the minus signal from negative numbers, so what iam trying to do is, use regex to iterate through the name columns (Where the minus signal went) and match lines with a regex, if it matches it multiplicates the values column by -1 or concatenate a minus in front of the number, but i tried both ways but neither of them changed the values column.

Here's the Dataframe

```
          date                                    name               value
519  25/02/2022                              LOREM IPSUM            598,72
520  25/02/2022                              LOREM IPSUM            656,56
523  25/02/2022                              LOREM IPSUM -          220,32
524  25/02/2022                              LOREM IPSUM -          339,76
```

The result I expect is

```
         date                                    name               value
519  25/02/2022                              LOREM IPSUM            598,72
520  25/02/2022                              LOREM IPSUM            656,56
523  25/02/2022                              LOREM IPSUM -         -220,32
524  25/02/2022                              LOREM IPSUM -         -339,76
```

I tried using

```
r1 = re.compile(r"- $|-$")

for item in diference["name"]:
  if r1.match(item):
    diference["value"] = diference["value"]*(-1)
```

And

```
r1 = re.compile(r"- $|-$")

 for item in diference["name"]:
   if r1.match(item):
     diference["value"] = "-" + diference["value"]
```

But as i said neither of them gave me an error nor changed something

Comment: So, you have commas as decimal separators? And you want to keep them? Or convert to floats with `.` as decimal separator? What is the type of the `value` column?

Comment: Yes commas are the decimal separator, when iam comparing values from two different columns i have to change the commas to dots, and change it back to commas after comparing, because it is the way we use it here in my country, so it doesn't really matter if they stay dots or commas. The only thing i want is to convert the values in the row that match regex to negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'].str.replace(',', '.'))
df.loc[df['name'].str.endswith('-'), 'value'] *= -1
```

*Details*

- `df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'].str.replace(',', '.'))` converts the string numbers to numbers
- `df.loc[df['name'].str.endswith('-'), 'value'] *= -1` multiplies with -1 all values in `value` column where the `name` column ends with a `-`.

See a Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'name': ['LOREM IPSUM ', 'LOREM IPSUM -'], 'value':['598,72', '339,76']})
df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'].str.replace(',', '.'))
df.loc[df['name'].str.endswith('-'), 'value'] *= -1
```

Output:

```
>>> df
            name   value
0   LOREM IPSUM   598.72
1  LOREM IPSUM - -339.76
```